# different apk names for each buildTypes

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-build-type

I need to get a release name of the file different from the name of the file that is generated with "Run 'app'" button. But if I add `archivesBaseName` in buildTypes `release` and `debug`, then both the file name are obtained from the lower buildTypes - in the code below is a `release`.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'
    def code
    def name

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode buildTime()
        versionName "2.2a"
        code = versionCode
        name = versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            archivesBaseName = "debugApp"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            proguardFile 'C:/app/proguard-rules.pro'
            archivesBaseName = "APP_" + name + "-build" + code
        }
    }
}
```

Is it some bug of Android Studio or i doing something wrong?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/32512076/5512274 . Some gradle versions have a bug with the archivesBaseName property.

Comment: @NarayanAcharya I've seen this answer, but i'm using classpath `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'`

Comment: I know this is very old,  but for anyone looking for a solution: you can use a task to conditionally set `archivesBaseName` https://stackoverflow.com/a/75334592/820841